# How to set breaks in ggplot 2 scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverselog")

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is below

```
x <- c(20, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0.5, 0.3)
y <- c(2e-42, 8e-20, 2e-15, 9e-9, 5e-7, 4e-7, 7e-5, 3e-3, 2e-2, 1e-1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 5e-2, 8e-3)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
```

I would like to plot x vs y. x axis is log10 scaled, y axis is both reversed and log10 scaled(the scale can be changed for a better visualization). I would also like to choose the breaks in the y axis as < 0.000001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1.

I tried the code below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y))+scale_x_log10() +scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverselog") + geom_point()
```

[image]

The breaks in y axis is not what I want. I tried the code below, while it doesn't work.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y))+scale_x_log10() +scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(seq(2e-42, 0.0001, 0.0000001),seq(0.0001, 0.001, 0.0003),seq(0.001, 0.01, 0.003),seq(0.01, 0.05, 0.02), seq(0.05, 0.1, 0.05), seq(0.1,0.5,0.4), seq(0.5, 0.99, 0.49)),trans = "reverselog") + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `scales` you can make use of `trans_new` to define a new transformation.
Starting by defining the function to transform the axis, the definition of its inverse is also required. Based on these functions `trans_new` is defined.

The diagram is then transformed on the y-axis by calling this function `coord_trans(y=log_reverse)`. In the following `scale_y_continuous` breaks, labels and limits are defined.

```r
x <- c(20, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0.5, 0.3)
y <- c(2e-42, 8e-20, 2e-15, 9e-9, 5e-7, 4e-7, 7e-5, 3e-3, 2e-2, 1e-1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 5e-2, 8e-3)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))

library(ggplot2)
# library(metR)
library(scales)

lab_y <- c( "< 0.000001", "0.0001", "0.001", "0.01", "0.05", "0.1", "0.5", "1")
brk_y <- c( 0.000001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1)


trans <- function(x) -log(x, 10)
inv <- function(x) -log(x, 10)

log_reverse <- trans_new(name = "log reverse",
                        transform = trans,
                        inverse = inv
                        )

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  coord_trans(y=log_reverse) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = brk_y,
    labels = lab_y,
    limits = c(0.00000000001, 1)
  )
```

[image]

PS: I personally do not think it is good idea to have a tick label with `<`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for.

The appearance of the labels may need tidying up: you could make the text size smaller with `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6))` or you could use fewer breaks.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)
library(scales)

lab_y <- c( "< 0.000001", "0.0001", "0.001", "0.01", "0.05", "0.1", "0.5", "1")
brk_y <- c( 0.000001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1)

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverselog", breaks = brk_y, labels = lab_y )+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>